# MPMoviePlayer not removing from superview

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am using the following code to play video files in MPMoviePlayerController

```
  NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"one" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL*  url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

    _movie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [_movie.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:_movie.view];
    _movie.fullscreen=YES;
    _movie.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
    [_movie prepareToPlay];
    [_movie play];
```

and

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(close:)name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:_movie];
```

and

```
- (void) close:(NSNotification *)notification {

    int reason = [[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] intValue];

    if(reason == MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped) {

        NSLog(@"Stop");

    }
    else if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded) {
        NSLog(@"Playback Ended ");
    }
    else if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited) {

        NSLog(@"Exited");
        [_movie.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    else if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError) {
        //error
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }    
}
```

I am able to get the Notification , and the Movieplayer is not removing from the superview.

What could be the problem ??

Comment: you want to remove mpmovieplayercontroller in userwillexited only?

Comment: Yes Exactly. I mean when the Done button is pressed.

Comment: Now, If I click the Done Button, The movie is gone (Screen is black). But the controls are still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this follow instructions:

when I listen to MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(doneButtonClick:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification 
                                           object:_movie];
```

And selector method:

```
-(void)doneButtonClick:(NSNotification*)aNotification{
  [_movie.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

(or)

**Better way to use mpmovieplayerviewcontroller in below tutorial**

http://mobiledevelopertips.com/video/getting-mpmovieplayercontroller-to-cooperate-with-ios4-3-2-ipad-and-earlier-versions-of-iphone-sdk.html

Comment: When Done Button is clicked, It is not calling MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification for me, It is calling MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification

Comment: try this notification [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(doneButtonClick:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification 
                                           object:_movie];

Comment: I tried that already , that notification is not sent for the control style MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen.

Comment: if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited) is called or not called in your code?

Comment: Can you tell me one more thing ?? If I use the control style as MPMovieControlStyleDefault , we are having the Done button as well as Double Headed arrow. If I press done button it is removing from superview. If I press double-arrow (near forward button) it is also removing from superview.

Comment: I will tell the exact problem am facing. If I use MPMovieControlStyleDefault, I am getting controls as Done and Double-headed arrow(near forward button). If I press Done button, remove from super view. If I press Double- headed arrow, it is also removing from super view (which shouldn't) and audio is playing in the background.

Comment: your problem is audio playing in background?

Comment: That is the reason I went for the MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen style. Which has only Done Button. And this is not calling the name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification but calling MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification. And also this style it is not removing from super view

Comment: you can try to hide movieplayer and before stop movieplayer like [_movie stop]; _movie.hidden=YES;

Comment: No. When the double-headed arrow is pressed, the default behavior should work. I mean, when pressing the double-headed arrow,it will move the controls to the footer. But here it is closing but audio able to hear, i.e running in BG

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13509/discussion-between-dinesh-and-perseus)

Comment: We are not having hidden property for MPMoviePlayerController.

Comment: Finally I used the MPMoviePlayerViewController. Which sends the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification when Done button is clicked